# How to access Junction Object fields

Tags: apex, junction-object

I have Three Objects A, B and C. C is junction Object

Through the Object of C , I want to access the fields of A and B.

I am doing it as

C.A.field__C

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

You should read through this [Relationship Queries](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) documentation that amongst other things explains the use of `__r` references.

If you have these custom objects:

```
A__c
B__c
C__c
```

the field reference would be:

```
C__c c = ...;
Object aField = c.A__r.Field__c;
```

Note that for standard objects e.g. Contact the reference fields don't follow this pattern but rather are usually just the same as the referenced object type (with the ID of the referenced object usually having an ID suffix).

Answer (score 3):

If C is your junction object then C has a reference to an A and a reference to a B

So in SOQL you could write something like

```
thingC__c anExampleC = [select my_thing_A__r.thing_A_field__c, my_thing_B__r.thing_B_field__c
                        from thingC__c
                        where id = '.....'];
```

Comment: so does that mean that I can refer any field in a by A.B.field_of_B__c

Comment: The junction object provides a many to many relationship. So any particular A could be related to zero, one or lots of B records. There will be one C record per junction between A and B.